# Rust oauth2 library without client secret

Tags: rust, oauth-2.0

I'm looking at implementing oauth2 in my rust application. It is an agent that will run on endpoints, so I do not want to store the client secret within the application.

I'm using the "resource owner password credential grant" type for authorisation.

From what I understand, my client application (the rust agent) should send the username/password to the authorisation server, which will send back a token. I can then use this token against the resource server (while the token is still valid).

Looking around, the most prominent rust crate for oauth2 seems to be "[oauth2](https://docs.rs/oauth2/3.0.0/oauth2/index.html)", which as far as I have seen is for use as a client (not server side).

What I do not understand is that every example they provide has you including the client secret. Has anyone got experience in using this library without the client secret? Or another rust crate that is better suited to what i'm trying to do?

Comment: I have used it without client secret but It was buggy. I ended with making pure requests.

Comment: thanks @asmmo, do you happen to have the piece of code for how you used it without the secret?